# Terraform lifecycle "Variables may not be used here"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm getting error when I try to run "Terraform init", what I'm missing here?

```
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│ 
│   on ../../resources/s3-bucket/main.tf line 12, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3-bucket":
│   12:     prevent_destroy = var.prevent_destroy
│ 
│ Variables may not be used here.
╵

╷
│ Error: Unsuitable value type
│ 
│   on ../../resources/s3-bucket/main.tf line 12, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3-bucket":
│   12:     prevent_destroy = var.prevent_destroy
│ 
│ Unsuitable value: value must be known
```

Resource:

```
    resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3-bucket" {
      bucket                  = var.bucket_name
      tags = {
        Name        = var.tags_name
        Environment = var.tags_environment
      }
      versioning { enabled = var.versioning }
      lifecycle {
        prevent_destroy = var.prevent_destroy
      }
      server_side_encryption_configuration {
        rule {
          apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
            sse_algorithm = var.encryption_algorithm
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Var:

```
    variable "prevent_destroy" {
        type = bool
        description = "Turn on or off lifecycle"
    }
```

Module:

```
    module "s3-bucket" {
        source                  = "../../resources/s3-bucket"
        region                  = var.region
        access_key              = var.access_key
        secret_key              = var.secret_key
        bucket_name             = var.bucket_name
        tags_name               = var.tags_name
        tags_environment        = var.tags_environment
        versioning              = var.versioning
        prevent_destroy         = var.prevent_destroy
        encryption_algorithm    = var.encryption_algorithm
    }
```

TFVARS:

```
    prevent_destroy     = false
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use variables in `lifecycle` blocks [1]:

> The `lifecycle` settings all affect how Terraform constructs and traverses the dependency graph. As a result, only literal values can be used because the processing happens too early for arbitrary expression evaluation.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#literal-values-only